# How to destroy Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one `Activity`. The `Activity` has two `Fragment`s.
Fragment A is Menu. Fragment B is Detail.

I try to Make other Fragment C in Fragment B, so, There are 3 Fragment in the `Activity`.
And I try to Replace Fragment B to Fragment D.

I guess Fragment B and C is dead.
BUT these Fragments is alive. Just Fragments are `onDestroyView()` state. I want `onDestroy()` or `onDetach()`.

What do I do for `Fragments.onDestroy()` or `onDetach()`? I can't destroy or change the `Activity`.

Comment: Are you replacing by adding to the back stack? If so then I don't expect the fragment to be destroyed. If you are then don't add the transaction to the back stack on a replace.

Answer (score 81):

If you don't remove manually these fragments, they are still attached to the activity. Your activity is not destroyed so these fragments are too.
To remove (so destroy) these fragments, you can call:

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(yourfragment).commit()
```

Hope it helps to you

Comment: This helped me with the dreaded "Duplicate id" crash. Thanks!

Comment: when a fragment is removed, which fragment life cycle method gets called? Similarly, when a fragment is replaced which method of the fragment life cycle gets called?

Comment: Wow, this makes Google's documentation for replace() totally wrong: ``This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.`` When in reality, only calling remove() destroys the fragment and replace doesn't.

Comment: I'm unable to kill my fragment this way. Where should this be called exactly?

Answer (score 12):

Give a try to this

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
    trans.remove((Fragment) object);
    trans.commit();

    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
```

Comment: Which Fragment class has destroyItem method to be overridden?

Comment: you can find this in FragmentPagerAdapter class but I don't think the question was asked for a view pager

Answer (score 12):

If you are in the fragment itself, you need to call this. Your fragment needs to be the fragment that is being called. Enter code:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(yourFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

or if you are using `supportLib`, then you need to call:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(yourFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend the commitAllowingStateLoss() method, that will cause you lots of pain, unless you are sure you are OK with lossing data.

Comment: Yes, that's sure. Its better to use commit! Still depends on the context

Answer (score 1):

> Use this if you're in the fragment.

```
@Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove((Fragment) youfragmentname).commitAllowingStateLoss();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin we can do this anywhere in our Fragment

```
 activity?.run {
     supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(this@MyFragment)
        .commitAllowingStateLoss()  
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is calling `parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit()`.
Remember that `fragment.onDestroy()` won't pop it up from the `parentFragmentManager.fragments` stack.
The complete example code will be:

```
 parentFragmentManager.fragments.onEach {
                if (it is SpecifiedFragment) {
                   parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(it).commit()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -4):

It's used in *Kotlin*

```
appCompatActivity?.getSupportFragmentManager()?.popBackStack()
```

Comment: This is popping the latest added fragment. This can pop a hidden fragment like a GlideFragmentManager, or another fragment in your UI, so popping without at least a TAG is a bad practice and will lead to issues at some point on your app.