# Destroying Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an android application where I followed http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html to setup.

However, I have quite a few fragments in the ViewPager (not at once) and I'd like to destroy them when I'm not on them. To put it into perspective, I have one fragment that gets created every time the ViewPager's getItem(int position) is called - which is around 365 times (one for each day of the year). All was good until I added an ImageView to one of the pages (12 in total at the end of it...) and now I'm running out of memory if I try view 3 of those page fragments.

My question is, how do I remove/destroy the fragment when its not the current page? I tried popping the BackStack of the FragmentManager, but that didn't work (it doesn't seem to have anything in the BackStack, but then again - I could have been calling it in the wrong place which was the getItem() function)

I'd provide code, but its quite a lot to look through for the important parts. It has the exact same structure as the Tutorial in the link above.

Thanks

Comment: head to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119203/how-to-destroy-fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you get memory issue after adding imageViews to pager, why not focus on the memory aspects of the bitmap you construct for the imageView just added to your app?

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Note that pictures from device cameras can be very, very big and can cause memory issues very quickly and , IMO you should focus first on that.

IMO , the standard ViewPager and standard Adapter are OK at managing memory, even if you have lots of Fragments that you cycle through the pager.

And, its a [little complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view) to take on the issue of explicitly destroying pages, reloading fragments in a ViewPager due to the amount of detail in collaboration among the pager and the adapter.

If you want to take on the complexity of the adapter and pager yourself, you will need to get into the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/efea2e772645ccd2d0de3e92fa8382d5444eab11/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) for the pager and for the adapter you select:

```
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter},
 * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter};
```

As you can see from many posts on the topic of managing fragments in a ViewPager, its not enough to simply call 'destroyItem()' on the adapter or to simply remove a fragment from the ListArray bound to the adapter before calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter. You also must know exactly how the operation of [getItemPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728076/when-should-getitemposition-consider-changes-of-an-items-position) works along with the ViewPager in order to get the result you want.

It will probably take lots of time to  work through the ViewPager approach .

Solve it if you can by first focus on the bitmaps.