# Is there a way to end a fragment from within the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains a timer. When the time is at `00:00` I want to end the fragment. Is there a function that I can call inside the fragment that destroys the fragment?

In contrast to the "possible dublicate" this question asks what to call from the fragment instead of what function to call from the activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to destroy Fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119203/how-to-destroy-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

You can not "end" a fragment like you'd end an activity, as a fragment is always a part of an activity.

You can, however, signal the activity to replace the countdown-fragment with another fragment using callbacks or other mechanisms like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

Comment: Or simply use interfaces to call a method of the activity from within the fragment.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "signaling the activity using callbacks". There are several possible ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This approach seems rather fine :

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

However if you have children fragments , it will not work.